# Neat way to make Dataset from RecurrenceTable

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion, dataset

I just learned that I can create a Dataset by combining *Dataset* and *Table* functions. For example:

```
d = RandomVariate[DemandProcess, nperiods];
dat = Table[<|
  "d" -> d[[i]],
  "underQ" -> Boole[d[[i]] > Q] (d[[i]] - Q),
  "overQ" -> Boole[d[[i]] <= Q] (-d[[i]] + Q),
  "under$" -> Boole[d[[i]] > Q] (d[[i]] - Q) cu,
  "over$" -> Boole[d[[i]] <= Q] (-d[[i]] + Q) co,
  "iQ" -> If[i == 1, Q, 0]
  |>, {i, 1, nperiods}];
dat = Dataset[dat]
```

[image: result of dataset on table]

For anyone interested in the background of this problem, this is a newsvendor model where *Q* is quantity of inventory to order in every period, *d* is a list of demand quantities per period, *underQ* is shortage of inventory, *under\$* is cost of the shortage, *cu* is the cost of unit shortage; *overQ*, *over\$*, *co* have similar meanings; rows are periods and inventory doesn't carry over.

Now, where I'm struggling is the *iQ* column: I want its consecutive values to depend on preceding values. I could achieve that, for example, by doing this:

```
RecurrenceTable[{iQ[t + 1] == 
  iQ[t] + Boole[iQ[t] < d[[t]]] cu - Boole[iQ[t] > d[[t]]] co, 
  iQ[1] == iQstart}, iQ, {t, 1, nperiods}]
```

I don't think that this is achievable by using *Table* function and I don't know how to combine *Dataset* function with the above *RecurrenceTable* code.

Please help and advise on how to keep the solution compact and neat. Thank you

Comment: For such a simple recurrence you gave you can directly do the same with `Table` so you can write `"iQ"->(q=q+1)` where of course `q=Q` is set before the table starts. But for more complicated recurrence you'll probably have to run the recurrence table first `q=RecurrenceTable[...]` then only create the dataset the same way you did but `"iQ"->q[[i]]`.

Comment: Thanks @SquareOne but my RecurrenceTable code shows a code that I made up to save me some typing, not the actual code. I should have realized that. I'll edit my question with the actual code.

Comment: Your actual code for the `RecurrenceTable` can be easily translated to `Table`. Run this for example:`q=iQstart ; Table[q=q+Boole[q<d[[t]]] cu - Boole[q>d[[t]]] co, {t,1,nperiods}]`.  Then, you can directly use it inside your `dat` command to build the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Just happened across this.  If I understand the situation, you're looking for an accumulation of iQ (over time) as you proceed *down* the dataset.  I do loads of this type of thing with time series.  I've simplified from your example, hope this helps:

```
dat[Query[<|
  "d" -> Query[All, "d"],
  "d(rand)" -> Query[All, "d(rand)"], 
  "d(accum)" -> Query[Accumulate, "d(rand)"]
|>]]
```

Comment: Please show that this addresses the question by including the result of your code.